# importing project in android studio and generating .apk

Tags: android, apk

I have a source code given by someone in which I have to make some changes. when I generate .apk from it in android studio whether signed or debug .apk. It does not run in my device by saying "app was already expired please use another version". But he also provides me a .apk from the same source which works. I don't know why the .apk generated in my android studio is not working. Is the files lock or what the problem. Please help me. Thanks,

Comment: Some api key is used by that app?

Comment: Yes, google map api key is used.

Comment: You will have to create your own api key to generate apk from your machine. You can get more details about generating api key from here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup

Comment: I generate my own api key and add it but it still give me the same message.

Comment: Did you change the package name of the project?

Comment: Change the package name of the project and generate api key for that package and then try to install

Comment: I have not restrict the api key. thats why i have not add peckage name

Comment: I generate api key for the changed peckage name but still give me the same message.